# How to use a property of a outer class in inner class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, inner-classes

I have this class:

```
class ItemsAdapter(
    val items: List<Item> = mutableListOf()
) {
    class ItemViewHolder(private val itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val clickedItem = items.get(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

Even if `items` object is defined in the outer class, it cannot be used in the inner class. How can I use the `items` object in the `onClick` function?

Comment: You should pass "items" list as an argument to ItemViewHolder.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu There's no "either or" there. `this@ItemsAdapter.items` works only with `inner`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mark ItemViewHolder as an `inner` class

```
inner class ItemViewHolder
```

More info on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html

Comment: Didn't know I should explicitly add that inner keyword. It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the members of an outer class in  the inner class, then you have to mark the inner class with `inner` keyword.

Mark your `ItemViewHolder` as `inner` and everything should work fine.

```
class ItemsAdapter(
    val items: List<Item> = mutableListOf()
) {
    inner class ItemViewHolder(private val itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val clickedItem = items.get(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `inner` Keyword

```
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ItemsAdapter(
    val items: List<Item> = mutableListOf()
) {
    inner class ItemViewHolder(private val itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val clickedItem = items.get(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```